# Run a GUI program at startup on top of X with no window manager

Tags: startup, gui, window-manager, desktop-environments

I want to start a program on top of X after startup. I want no desktop manager, nor window manager, but I just want to start a single program like Firefox after startup.

Is there a standard way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I remember way back I had to set up my own X stuff by writing a .xinitrc file and running startx. I suspect that won't work well with modern xorg/distros.

Alternatively, I notice that there's a file named `/etc/X11/xinit` that just launches the X session manager. I expect you could just edit that to do something else.

BTW, I think you probably *do* want a window manager or you might have trouble with Firefox. The default one is named `x-window-manager`.

---

Ok, here's a better answer ....

Create a new file,  `~/.xsessionrc`:

```
STARTUP=
```

Create a new file, `~/.Xsession` [*Note the capital X*]:

```
x-window-manager &
firefox
```

Logout, and login again.

Comment: but it is not working on ubuntu

Comment: Which 'it' isn't working?

Comment: Ok, I did a bit of checking and found a better way ... edited above.

Comment: If you want to skip logging in, you can use nodm as your desktop manager.

Comment: x-window-manager seems to bring of a blue background before the app loads.
Where is the x-window manager loading the backrgound from?